# Cookies not sent on redirect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, proxy, passport.js

I am building a react web application with a separate back-end express api that manages all the calls, including passporting and setting cookies. Let's call the back-end service 'api.com' and the front-end service 'react.com'. I'm using passporting with an existing provider (spotify) and after the authorization succeeds, a cookie is set on api.com. The idea is that the user interacts with react.com and requests are made to api.com via a proxy.

If I'm just testing in my browser and I make a call to api.com/resource, the cookie is automatically set. I know this because I've added a bit of logging and also because the requests that require authorization are succeeding via the cookie.

However, when I make calls to api.com from react.com via the proxy, the cookie is not set. Is this expected behavior when proxying? It seems odd that the cookie is set when I call api.com directly, but it is not set when it is redirected. Is there a way around this? My thought would be to communicate the cookie from api.com to react.com, save it there, and send it on all subsequent requests, but that seems overkill. I'm also wondering if maybe I should be setting the cookie on react.com instead of api.com.

I've tried in both Firefox and Chrome, and if it makes a difference, I'm using axios for the requests on react.com.

```
const request = axios({
  method:'get',
  url:'/api/resource'
});
```

This gets proxied as follows (still on react.com), using express-http-proxy:

```
app.use('/', proxy('api.com', {
  filter: (req) => {
    return (req.path.indexOf('/api') === 0);
  }
}));
```

But once this hits api.com, any authentication fails, because the cookie is not present.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your question, I think you're not considering that cookies are set to host name.

So in the first case the hostname is same and its okay, but in the second case the browser's cookies are not set for react.com

So trying to set the cookie on react.com should work.

I would have asked for a clarification using a comment but I don't have enough reputation for that yet.